# How to add header and footer at sales order print page

Tags: magento-2.1, layout, blocks, sales

I think by not mentioning magento version I made a mistake. This question is related to Magento 2.1.5

I need specific answer regarding

```
How to add header and footer at sales order print page? i.e.  /sales/order/print/order_id/3/
```

I have tried but being fresh at magento don't know how and where to add header and footer blocks in xml file.

Immediate help/guideline is required.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `page.xml` find the main structure tag named `print`. There you can see no header section added there as `default` handler has.

copy the whole `header` block from `default` handler to `print` handler. There you will see only

> `<block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header"/>` in print handler.

Now after adding the whole `header` block in `print` handler you need to go to `app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\page\print.phtml` and add `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?>` after `body` class.

Now you are done. It will look like this

[image]

Hope you have got the idea about footer also. Enjoy !!

Comment: Is this solution for magento 2. My mistake i didn't mentioned magento version in question

Comment: No its M1. But you can get the whole idea.

Comment: i have tried many things if possible can you help me for the solution in magento 2

Comment: @AdilNaeem Have you got solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Find `your_root_folder/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout/print.xml`

**You will get layout file responsible for print page layout that can be modified accordingly as per need**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <attribute name="class" value="page-print"/>
        <referenceContainer name="header.container" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav" remove="true"/>
        <referenceContainer name="footer-container" remove="true"/>
        <move element="logo" destination="main.content" before="-" />
        <move element="copyright" destination="main.content" after="-" />
        <referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="sales.order.print.js" template="Magento_Theme::html/print.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

copy above file to your `vendor/theme_name/Magento_theme/layout/print.xml`

**just add your header & footer block to display your custom header & footer**

> you can remove also header & footer or modify layout as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

1) need add print.xml to your theme
like - app/design/frontend/My/shop/Magento_Theme/layout/print.xml

2) and code of XML

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="main.content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" after="copyright" name="sales.order.print.footer" template="Magento_Theme::html/print-footer.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

3) add file app/design/frontend/My/shop/Magento_Theme/templates/html/print-footer.phtml , where need insert your content

ready :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Override sales_order_print.xml file to your theme -

> app/design/frontend/[Vendore]/[Theme]/Magento_Sales/layout/sales_order_print.xml

2. Update sales_order_print.xml file based on below code

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
       <update handle="sales_order_print_renderers" />
       <update handle="sales_order_item_price"/>
       <update handle="print" />
       <body>
       <attribute name="class" value="account"/>
       <referenceContainer name="page.main.title">
       <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\PrintShipment"
              name="order.status"
              template="Magento_Sales::order/order_status.phtml"
              cacheable="false" />
       <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\PrintShipment"
              name="order.date"
              template="Magento_Sales::order/order_date.phtml"
              cacheable="false" />
   </referenceContainer>
   <referenceContainer name="header.container" remove="false"/>
   <referenceContainer name="content">
       <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\PrintShipment"
              name="sales.order.print"
              template="Magento_Sales::order/view.phtml"
              cacheable="false">
           <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Items" name="order_items" template="Magento_Sales::order/items.phtml">
               <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="sales.order.print.renderers" as="renderer.list" />
               <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Totals" name="order_totals" template="Magento_Sales::order/totals.phtml">
                   <arguments>
                       <argument name="label_properties" xsi:type="string">colspan="4" class="mark"</argument>
                       <argument name="value_properties" xsi:type="string">class="amount"</argument>
                   </arguments>
                   <block class="Magento\Tax\Block\Sales\Order\Tax" name="tax" template="Magento_Tax::order/tax.phtml">
                       <action method="setIsPlaneMode">
                           <argument name="value" xsi:type="string">1</argument>
                       </action>
                   </block>
               </block>
           </block>
       </block>
       <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Info" as="sales.order.print.info" name="sales.order.print.info" template="Magento_Sales::order/info.phtml"/>
       </referenceContainer>
       <referenceContainer name="footer-container" remove="false"/>
       <move element="copyright" destination="footer-container" after="-" />
       <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="additional.product.info" template="Magento_Theme::template.phtml"/>
    </body>
   </page>
   ```
3. Clear cache

Hope it's helpfull.